# How to remove ASCII newline characters (nl) and carrier return characters (cr) from a string in php

Tags: php, preg-replace, ascii

I have to remove and replace ASCII newline characters (nl) and carrier return characters (cr) from a php string.

I tried using following statement to replace all ASCII (nl) char from $input with blank space but didn't work:

```
preg_replace('/[\x0a]+/',' ',$input);
```

then i tried to replace all the ASCII control characters with blank spaces, following is the statement:

```
ereg_replace('[[:cntrl:]]', ' ', $encoded); // didn't work
```

I tried the following statements also but no luck with them:

```
ereg_replace("[:cntrl:]", "", $pString);
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $input);
preg_replace('/[\x00-\x09\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x7F]/', '', $input);
```

What is the regex expression to remove ASCII newline characters (nl) and carrier return characters (cr) from a php string?

I referred to few link below :
[ASCII Table](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html)
[Regular Expressions](http://w3.pppl.gov/info/grep/Regular_Expressions.html)
[Regular expression posix](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html)

Comment: "The following links might help you", why can't they help you ?   SO isn't a "give me the code" type website !

Answer (score 4):

Can't you just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)?

```
str_replace( array("\n", "\r"), "", $stringinput );
```

Answer (score 3):

Why use a regexp? What's wrong with

```
str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $string);
```

? In PHP, the characters \n and \r are guaranteed to be the actual newline and carriage return points: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 1):

if you insist using `preg_replace()` for such a simple task you can use:

```
$result = preg_replace('/[\r\n]/', '', $subject);
```

Although, you **should** use `str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), "", $string);` as advised previoulsy.